# How to restart a specific program in Supervisor without affecting other processes?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, supervisord

I am using Supervisor to manage multiple processes on my server. Each process is defined as a separate program in the Supervisor configuration file. I need to restart a specific program without affecting the other running processes.

Is there a way to restart a single program in Supervisor without restarting all the processes managed by Supervisor? I want to avoid any downtime or interruption to the other processes.

I have tried using systemctl restart supervisor <program_name>, but it restarts all the processes instead of just the specified one. Is there a command or configuration change I can make to achieve a targeted restart of a specific program?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to accomplish this in Supervisor. Thank you!